# HTTP 404 Not Found error when running Java rest services

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 error after deploying my web services to Apache 10.1.

They use to work in Apache 9. I had update some libraries to get my project to work for JDK17.

Here is my code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stableapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>EsarClientService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>EsarClientService</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.39</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.stableapps.esarclientservice;

import com.stableapps.esarclientservice.model.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission;
import com.stableapps.esarclientservice.model.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

/**
 * Jersey REST client generated for REST resource:COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService
 * [COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission]<br>
 * USAGE:
 * <pre>
 *        EsarServiceRestClient client = new EsarServiceRestClient();
 *        Object response = client.XXX(...);
 *        // do whatever with response
 *        client.close();
 * </pre>
 *
 */
public class EsarServiceRestClient {

    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/EsarClientService/webresources";

    public EsarServiceRestClient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission");
    }

    public COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse post(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission submission)
            throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget
                .request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(
                        javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(
                                submission, 
                                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
                        ),
                        COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse.class
                );
    }

    public COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse postAckRetrieval(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission submission) throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget.path("AckRetrieval")
                .request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(
                        javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(
                                submission,
                                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
                        ),
                        COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse.class);
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }

}
```

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.stableapps.esarclientservice;

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmitContext;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.DefaultWssContainer;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.crypto.KeyMaterialWssCrypto;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Attachment;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Submit;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.project.ProjectFactoryRegistry;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException;
import com.stableapps.esarclientservice.model.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission;
import com.stableapps.esarclientservice.model.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;

@Path("COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission")
public class COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission
     */
    public COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService() {
    }

    /**
     * POST method for updating or creating an instance of COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService
     *
     * @param submission representation for the resource
     * @return
     * @throws org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     * @throws com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException
     * @throws com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request.SubmitException
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse post(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission submission) throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException, Request.SubmitException, Exception {
        File attachment = createAttachmentFromBytes(submission.getAttachment());

        Map valuesMap = BeanUtils.describe(submission);

        //Submits the request 
        WsdlSubmit<WsdlRequest> submit
                = callCOREEnvelopeBatchSubmission(valuesMap, attachment);

        //Check first if the status is error.  If ERROR then print the stacktrace of the error
        COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse response = COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse.builder()
                .PayloadID(submission.getPayloadID())
                .Status(submit.getStatus().name())
                .build();

        if (submit.getStatus() == Submit.Status.ERROR) {
            response.setContent(submit.getError().getMessage());
            submit.getError().printStackTrace(System.err);
            return response;
        }

        response.setContent(submit.getResponse().getContentAsXml());
        //Print the response XML
        System.out.println(submit.getResponse().getContentAsXml());

        return response;
    }
```

[404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLK0Y.png)

[Server is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUacr.png)

Trying to get code to work on Apache 10.1.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?  Feels like something changes from Apache 9 to Apache 10.1.